# Custom UITabBarController with different item colours

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

What would be the correct approach to make a UITabBarController similar to this one from the Asana iOS App (button in the middle has a different colour than the others)?

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the background color:

```
tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

For the images, you can just set the image of your tab bar item.

In your Tab Bar Controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

var tabBar = self.tabBar

var image = UIImage(named: "image")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)

tabBar.items![0].selectedImage = image

}
```

Comment: I have tried to do this, but for some reason absolutely nothing will happen... And I have no clue why. I have tried to see if the array is empty, if the elements are accessible and so on... Does the image have to be of a certain type or it doesn't matter? @penatheboss

Comment: @alexclp I am not sure why it is not working. Sorry. You might want to do some more research on specific things such as the types of images